# Link JIRA - Bitbucket different names

Tags: jira, dvcs, bitbucket

We are trying to link a jira project and a Bitbucket repository with different names using  DVCS

The jira project has the name LAMB
And the bitbucket repository name is lambdev

I was working fine when both had the same name but now that they have different name, I cannot see the commit history in the commit "Tab" of my cases.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BitBucket :

1. Go to the project settings
2. Go to link
3. Delete the link that has been written by the DVCS extension of Jira
4. Click add a new link
5. Enter infos.